# Sub- and Supertypes, Methods, and Conversion

Tags: java, methods, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I am currently reading the Second Edition of Barbara Liskov's quite good *Program Development in Java: Abstraction, Specification, and Object-Oriented Design* (2000) for a graduate course. For reference, I am, for this question, consulting Section 2.4.2: Conversions and Overloading (p.27-29). Liskov is discussing method overloading and what Liskov calls the compiler's identification of the "'most specific'" (p. 28) method when supplied actual parameters for an overloaded call.

Here's the example Liskov provides the following overloaded method `foo`:

```
void foo (T a, int x) // defn. 1
void foo (S b, long y) // defn. 2
```

And the following call - which Liskov states is *not legal*:

```
o.foo(e, 3)
```

Here's what we know about our actual parameters:

1. `S` is a subtype of T.
2. Parameter `e` is a variable of type `S`

In my mind, this is a legal call, theoretically. The call `o.foo(e, 3)` is the same as making the call more specific (if I am thinking like the compiler when comparing apparent types):

`o.foo((T) e, 3)`

Obviously, `e` will only have access to the reduced, common behavior of the supertype when making this call; however, is it not still a legal call?

On a smaller scale:

`Object o = s` is legal where `s` evaluates to type `String` (just for the sake of a citation, too: Liskov, p. 26).

Why am I wrong? What am I not understanding?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. `o.foo(e, 3)` doesn't compile because it is ambiguous. Are you asking why it's ambiguous?

Comment: Yes, I was. See answer, below. +1 to you. I'm trying to get back in the CS mindset, i.e. the eye for the specifics. This is just one of those moments where I wasn't thinking.

Comment: I see. I didn't notice it was your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I showed this question to a computer science buddy of mine. And, now that I know the answer, I feel like a dummy (he asked me the question, "Yeah, it's legal; but, how does the compiler know which method to call?"); however - now that I've had my 'Oh, duh!' moment - I think the answer will still be helpful to those who are momentarily stuck in the same position I was:

Here, the question is not the legality of the call (were `//defn. 1` the only available method, the call would be absolutely legal). It is a question - as stated in the question, above - of "most specific" and the object `e` is not the problem.

The actual parameter `3` of type `int` is the problem.

Why? `int` is legally widened to type `long`; therefore, the compiler does not know which of the methods to call as both calls could receive these actual parameters.